# iOS Share Extension NSURLSession not working on iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, nsurlsession, ios8-share-extension, ios9.1

So I have this iOS Share Extension for my app that sends a result to my server in `didSelectPost()` when the 'POST' button is clicked.
It all works fine on simulator; the request is sent and I can see data packets going out in Charles.

On iOS 9, the Share Extension launches correctly, but the request is not sent in `didSelectPost` function.

I'm not sure if it's something wrong with my Share Extension or the `NSURLSession`.

The code -

```
- (void)didSelectPost {

    //Get session configuration
    NSString * const configName = @"com.xx.xxx";
    self.sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:configName];
    self.sessionConfiguration.sharedContainerIdentifier = @"group.xx.ShareURL";

    //Init NSURLSession
    self.session  = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfiguration];
    NSURLRequest *request = [self postContentToService:self.shareUrl.absoluteString];

    //post request
    self.sessionTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request];

    //resume
    [self.sessionTask resume];

    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Might be worth checking on whether it's an [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-711/) issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using HTTP instead of HTTPS, and the [ATP](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) thing is blocking all my NSURLRequests, without ANY form of noticing.

We pushed our server team to switch to allowing HTTPS and used HTTPS connections, everything works fine now.